# What can I do for this error in my SVR code in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code for SVR regressror:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('E:\\/Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)
y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

But there's the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=6.5.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

This is Position_Salaries.csv
[image]

What can I do for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback really explains the issue: the **`predict`** method expects a **bidimensional array** so you can either reshape your input as it suggests:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(np.array([6.5]).reshape(1,1))
```

or even pass a 2D version of your argument already:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(np.array([[6.5]]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Sorry, there's also the error "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  45000.   50000.   60000.   80000.  110000.  150000.  200000.  300000.
  500000. 1000000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample." when I run "y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)"

Comment: Could you please tell me what can I do for this? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. It's the same exact problem, except this time you passed a 1D array and not a scalar. Again, you can reshape it to 2D: y= sc_y.fit_transform(np.array(y).reshape(1, -1))

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm so sorry. I've done but this time there's error "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1, 10) instead" for command "regressor.fit(X, y)".